# How to use Open Atrium 2 for document managment

Tags: 7, distributions

In the past I have used Open Atrium 1 as an intranet site making use of the document management system.

[image]

I can't work out how to do something similar in OA2. From the [documentation](http://docs.openatrium.com/content/sections) I have found:

> News section - for document management, wikis, or articles

So I have created a News section. It looks like I can create a Document Page and add attachments to it. Do I no longer have the options to create files and folders. Just document pages and attachments?

Comment: Have you figured something out?

Comment: @Plux not yet :(

Comment: Did you install Aegir with Open Atrium?

Comment: @SofiaA no I did not.

Answer (score 1):

The 2.30 version of Open Atrium supports folders out-of-the-box through the [oa_folders module](https://www.drupal.org/project/oa_folders).

On earlier versions I have used a customized news section type and calling it Folders or Filesharing. With a clear workflow established with the people working on it, you can then have each document page being a folder, where all space members can add or remove further documents. It was obviously a limited solution, but made the purpose. Now we have a better OA world :)